# Problem submitting to testflight with 4.8.1

Tags: dji-sdk

I upgraded both the DJISDK and DJIUXSDK to v4.8.1, the builds are working as expected, but when I try to submit the solution to testflight I get a complaint about DJIUXSDK.framework/Assets.car. I have not done any modifications of the Assets.

Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at 'Payload/mydjiapp.app/Frameworks/DJIUXSDK.framework/Assets.car' can't be processed. Rebuild your app, and all included extensions and frameworks, with the latest GM version of Xcode and resubmit.

I am building the solution with Xcode 10.1.

My podfile:

```
target 'mydjiapp' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for mobilegroundstation
  pod 'DJI-SDK-iOS', '4.8.1'
  pod 'DJI-UXSDK-iOS', '4.8.1'
  pod 'DJIWidget', '~> 1.2'
end
```

Is there any obvious solution to this that I am missing?

Comment: Are you using the built-in most up-to-date App Loader to submit the app? The App Loader can sometimes fall behind the installed Xcode version, and it'll result in this error.

Also make sure that the setting "Rebuild with Bitcode" is turned off during the submission process. The bitcode setting should also be turned off inside the Xcode project.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct about the xcode version beeing the issue. I am using Azure Devops to build the app and the submit task is using fastlane to submit the app. Fastlane uses the default xcode version while I am building it with the 10.1 version of xcode